# extjs: creating Config block from json does not config e.g. tab title

Tags: extjs

Excerpt from json file ...

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "xtype": "tabbarcontext",
        "ptype": "tabbarcontext",
        "pstype": "maintab",
        "activeTab": 0,
        //"title": "NotTitleConfig",
        "config": [
            {"title": "TitleConfig"}
        ],
        "items": [
            {
                "xtype": "panel",
                "ptype": "tab",
                "layout": {
                    "type": "border"
                },
```

when this json is poked into the Viewport ...

```
 Ext.apply(me, {
        // we are adding TabBar with 4 tabs to Viewport
        items:  appItems // json retrieved from store
```

the tab panel is created, the activeTab = 0, but config: has not set the title. Commenting into the json file the code "title": "NotTitleConfig" does set the tab title. Why is this? tia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config is expected to be a JavaScript object not a JSON string. The following should work

```
Ext.apply(me, { items: Ext.JSON.decode(appItems) });
```

Comment: thanks for looking at this. Above gives me "decode invalid json string". Since the json loads straight into Viewport.items successfully - it only being that config: is not being applied - this error surprised me. I am loading the json from appDataStore.proxy.reader.rawData since this worked w/o conversion ... is there a better store property to grab? Would appreciate more explanation of the above .... having a hard time understanding why all the tabs, grids, forms and fields get displayed correctly when I dump rawData straight into Viewport.item and just config: seems to get ignored. tia

Comment: @MicC Well that was pretty much the answer; the JSON is invalid. As I wrote above, apply cannot handle a JSON string is has to be a Object. That is why it fails. Using the rawData from the ready is the right way imo.